# Latex bibiography on Fedora 18

Tags: pdftex, texmaker

I'm using texmaker

I'm getting  a problem, my citations are not being generated in spite of me putting the citations,

**here is my LaTeX file:**

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    As well as having written a book on this topic~\cite{Conway2000}, 
    he has also been the subject of articles.
    \bibliography{Master}
    \end{document}
```

**here is my Master.bib:**

```
@Book{Conway2000,
author = {Damian Conway},
title = {Object {O}riented {P}erl: {A} comprehensive guide to concepts and programming techniques},
publisher = {Manning Publications Co.},
year = {2000},
address = {Connecticut, USA}
}
```

**How the file is being displayed:**

[image]

**Log file:**

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2013/dev) 

    (format=pdflatex 2013.3.3) 6 MAR 2013 14:44
    entering extended mode
    restricted \write18 enabled.
    %&-line parsing enabled.
    **test.tex
    (./test.tex
    LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
    Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, po
    lish, ukenglish, usenglishmax, basque, bokmal, nynorsk, french, danish, portugu
    ese, spanish, dutch, swedish, hungarian, italian, finnish, german, ngerman, swi
    ssgerman, ukrainian, russian, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, mala
    yalam, marathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, romanian, turkmen, croatian, fri
    ulan, estonian, afrikaans, uppersorbian, ethiopic, greek, irish, coptic, indone
    sian, farsi, pinyin, latin, galician, bulgarian, icelandic, interlingua, catala
    n, welsh, czech, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabic, sanskrit, slovak, latvian, serbi
    an, serbianc, kurmanji, mongolian, mongolianlmc, esperanto, german-x-2012-05-30
    , ngerman-x-2012-05-30, slovenian, turkish, lithuanian, armenian, romansh, load
    ed.
    (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
    Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
    File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    )
    \c@part=\count79
    \c@section=\count80
    \c@subsection=\count81
    \c@subsubsection=\count82
    \c@paragraph=\count83
    \c@subparagraph=\count84
    \c@figure=\count85
    \c@table=\count86
    \abovecaptionskip=\skip41
    \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
    \bibindent=\dimen102
    ) (./test.aux)
    \openout1 = `test.aux'.
    LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
    LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
    LaTeX Warning: Citation `Conway2000' on page 1 undefined on input line 4.
    No file test.bbl.
    [1
    {/usr/share/texlive/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)
    LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
    )
    Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
    205 strings out of 493499
    2164 string characters out of 3143833
    48363 words of memory out of 3000000
    3595 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
    3948 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
    953 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
    23i,4n,21p,155b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
    </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></us
    r/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
    Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 24051 bytes).
    PDF statistics:
    16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
    10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
    0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
    1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Did you run BibTeX after LaTeX, then LaTeX again twice?

Comment: ohh, so i have to run latex, then bibtex then latex

Comment: @JosephWright, yes it works, ok

Comment: is there any direct command to this task??